# SIGSEGV accessing parameters of a structure in C

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I have written a basic data structure to solve a recursion problem in C. I don't understand why in one particular case I get a segmentation fault, even if in the other cases seems to work just fine.
Here's just the main part of the code: if you have the patience, [here](https://github.com/aleLoPrete/APA/blob/master/s258684_3/L8/E02/main.c)'s the full code.

```c
typedef struct{
    char color;
    int val;
}pipe;

typedef struct _tile tile;

struct _tile{
    pipe pipe1;
    pipe pipe2;
    int inUse;
};

typedef struct{
    tile *theTiles;
    tile *possibleTiles;
    int tileNum;
    int numInUse;
}tileCollection;

typedef struct{
    tile *tilePointer;
    int rotation;
}box;

typedef struct{
    box **board;
    box **solMax;
    int nCol;
    int nRow;
}boardWrap;


void findMax(boardWrap *theBoardWrap, tileCollection *theTileColl, int col, int row){

    if(col == (theBoardWrap->nCol-1)){//se sono arrivato alla fine della riga
        if(row == (theBoardWrap->nRow -1)){//sono arrivato alla fine della scacchiera
            if(evaluateScore(theBoardWrap)){// se la soluzione è massima
                theBoardWrap->solMax = theBoardWrap->board; // copio la soluzione max
            }
            return;
        }
        findMax(theBoardWrap, theTileColl, 0, row+1);//ricorro sulla riga successiva, alla prima colonna
    }

    if(theBoardWrap->board[col][row].tilePointer != NULL){//se la casella è già occupata
            findMax(theBoardWrap, theTileColl, col+1, row); //ricorro sulla colonna successiva
    }
    else{//se la casella è vuota
        for(int i = 0; i < (theTileColl->tileNum * 2); i++){//ciclo che scorre tutte le possibili piastrelle inseribili
            if(theTileColl->possibleTiles[i].inUse == 0){//controllo se la posso mettere
                theTileColl->possibleTiles[i].inUse = 1;//la marco come inserita
                //inserimento piastrella
                theBoardWrap->board[col][row].tilePointer = &theTileColl->possibleTiles[i];//inserisco la piastrella
                findMax(theBoardWrap, theTileColl, col+1, row);//ricorro sulla colonna successiva
                theTileColl->possibleTiles[i].inUse = 0;//BACKTRACK
            }
        }
    }
}

int evaluateScore(boardWrap *theBoardWrap){//ritorna '1' se il valore attuale è maggiore del Max passato, '0' se non è così
    int scoreBoard1, scoreBoardMax;

    scoreBoardMax = boardScoreCalc(theBoardWrap, theBoardWrap->solMax);
    scoreBoard1 = boardScoreCalc(theBoardWrap, theBoardWrap->board);
    if(scoreBoard1 > scoreBoardMax) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
            return 0;
    }

int boardScoreCalc(boardWrap *theBoardWrap, box **board){//se passo la la board by reference ho un SIGSEGV, se la passo by value no
    int flagRowColor = 0, flagColColor = 0;
    int totScoreRow = 0;
    int totScoreCol = 0;
    int rowPoints[theBoardWrap->nRow], colPoints[theBoardWrap->nCol];

    for(int i = 0; i < theBoardWrap->nRow; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < theBoardWrap->nCol; j++){
            //calcolo il punteggio per la riga
            if(j == 0){//inizio riga
                rowPoints[i] = board[i][j].tilePointer->pipe1.val;
                flagRowColor = 1;
            }
            else if(matchColor(theBoardWrap->board[i][j].tilePointer->pipe1.color,theBoardWrap->board[i][j-1].tilePointer->pipe1.color) && flagRowColor){
                rowPoints[i] += board[i][j].tilePointer->pipe1.val;
            }
            else{
                rowPoints[i] = 0;
                flagRowColor = 0;
            }
            //calcolo il punteggio per le colonne
            if(i == 0){//inizio colonna
                colPoints[j] = board[i][j].tilePointer->pipe2.val;
                flagColColor = 1;
            }
            else if(matchColor(theBoardWrap->board[i][j].tilePointer->pipe1.color,theBoardWrap->board[i-1][j].tilePointer->pipe1.color) && flagColColor){//HERE I GET SEGSIGV
                colPoints[j] += board[i][j].tilePointer->pipe2.val;
            }
            else {
                colPoints[j] = 0;
                flagColColor = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < theBoardWrap->nRow; i++){
        totScoreRow += rowPoints[i];
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < theBoardWrap->nCol; j++){
        totScoreCol *= colPoints[j];
    }
    return totScoreCol + totScoreRow;
}
```

Comment: Where does the segmentation fault occur?

Comment: It occurs when I call the function "matchColor", in "boardScoreCalc" function.

Comment: Your recursive function `findMax` calls `evaluateScore` which then calls `boardScoreCalc`, in which integer array is defined (`int rowPoints[theBoardWrap->nRow], colPoints[theBoardWrap->nCol];`), which might be stack space consuming. In one word, your recursive function may cause stack overflow and once stack overflew, SIGSEGV is signaled.

Comment: @YingyuYOU how is that related to the `matchColor` function?

Comment: @YingyuYOU thank you. Debugging I can see that it happens after 9 calls(the number of the box in the board), therefore the first time `boardScoReCalc` is called. Furthermore, I pass the main structure by pointer...
Do you think it could already give me stack overflow?

Comment: @Dinu Calling to `matchColor` (in fact to any function) requires some stack space, for example, to push returning address (and sometimes for some CPU architecture to pass parameters), if stack space almost used out, then segment fault occurs when calling to functions when stack boundary is crossed over.

Comment: @AlessandroLoPrete Pointers on x86_64 machines are 8 bytes. In comparison with the arrays that you declare they are insignificant.

Comment: @AlessandroLoPrete Aside from the SIGSEGV, you may need to separate the parts in which you calculate the score for rows and for columns to get accurate results. For columns you may want to have the j in the outer for loop.

Comment: @AlessandroLoPrete Nine times looks not possible causing stack overflew normally. Before calling to `matchColor`, there are several parameters require de-referencing pointers or array indexing, check if they caused segment fault, e.g. de-referencing a NULL pointer or uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I launched your program with your input data. No matter your program crashes because of absent input files. But according to GDB output your program does not fill `theBoardWrap->board[2][0].tilePointer` field at line 241 and tries to dereference it. My advice is to learn to use debugger (like GDB), to use assertions from `<assert.h>`, to handle manually allocated memory very accurately, to perform at least comparison to `NULL` pointer, like this:

```
assert(theBoardWrap != NULL);
assert(theBoardWrap->board[i][j].tilePointer != NULL);
assert(theBoardWrap->board[i-1][j].tilePointer != NULL);
```

And no, it is definitely not a stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I usually use the CLion debugger, is GDB that better?
I've tried with assertions, but I wasn't been able to catch the problem though.